# how to implement a check box in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a checkbox

```
<td><strong>Online Ordering: </strong></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="OnlineOrdering" value="<%=OnlineOrdering%>" <% if OnlineOrdering = True then response.write "checked='Checked'" end if %>/></td>
```

How do i capture whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked when form is submitted?

```
OnlineOrdering = request.form("OnlineOrdering")
```

this does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should assign a true/false to the variable OnlineOrdering:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    OnlineOrdering = (Request.Form("OnlineOrdering") <> "")
End If
```

Comment: It's an experience :). I'm sure you worked it out but the code evaluates whether the posted value OnlineOrdering is not blank - if it's not [blank] then it was checked, if it is blank then it was unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

I found this post because I was trying to solve the same problem.  I have a solution that seems to work well.

In the HTML form, create dynamically generated checkboxes.  The value of **this_box_id** used below can be any unique number.  In my case it was the primary key (autonumber) for that question from the SQL Database . Dynamically generated the check boxes with an associated hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="check_box_indicator" value="<%=this_box_id%>">
<input type="checkbox" name="box_id<%=this_email_selection_id%>" 
value="<%=this_box_id%>">
```

When asp returns the values for this, it will return multiple values for **check_box_indicator**.  Here's a sample query string snippet:

```
...&check_box_indicator=78&box_id78=78&check_box_indicator=98&check_box...
```

On the next page, ASP will read through the form data.  It will find EVERY check_box_indicator and it's value.  That value can be used to check the value of the associated checkbox.  If that checkbox comes back, it was checked, if it doesn't you will know that it wasn't checked.  In the sample above, checkbox 78 was checked and so the box_id78 value was passed, while checkbox 98 was not and box_id98 was not sent.  Here's the code to use this.

```
For Each this_box_id In Request.Form("check_box_indicator") 'check EVERY box'

   box_state = Request.Form("box_id"&this_box_id) 'collect passed values only'

   if box_state  > 0 then
       store_value = "y"
   else
       store_value = "n"
   end if

   ' you now have the this_box_id number identifying this item in the DB, '
   ' the value of the check box, if it was passed '
   ' and a definite y or n value '

Next
```

With the example querystring, you will get 78 y, 98 n